# NSURLResponse comes quickely in Simulator but on actual Device it comes after some time or returns NULL

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am creating a application which calls Web service on every view-controller.The Application runs fine on Simulator but on actual device, it runs very slowly or sometimes it returns null response that's why app crashes due to null response from sever.Is there any solution to solve this issue.I am very new to objective-c programming.Please suggest me a way to solve the issue. Thanks a lot.:)

here I am adding my part of the code which sends request to a web-service and receives response.

```
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someurl.com/somewebservice.asmx"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue:@"somehost.in" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"someUrl/someWebMethod" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection =
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    NSURLResponse *response1 = [[NSURLResponse alloc] init];;
    self.webResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    self.response = [[NSURLResponse alloc] init];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"Printing response...\n");
    NSLog(@"%@",response);
}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.webResponseData  appendData:data];
}
```

Comment: Check your device connection.

Comment: Thank You Nekak for reply.I am using wi-fi connection.

Comment: But you're not going to show us the actual code?

Comment: I agree with matt, show your code and maybe we can help you much better.

Comment: I have added the code to question.Can you tell me whats going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `sendSynchronousRequest`. Don't. Never, never, *never* network synchronously on the main thread.

Comment: Also, if you have no need for backwards compatibility, you should not be using NSURLConnection at all. It is superseded by NSURLSession.

Comment: But Sir,In case if it is needed to wait for the response,then what should be done?

Comment: "But Sir,In case if it is needed to wait for the response,then what should be done? ". Don't use sendSynchronousRequest, use the asynchronous APIs instead. (You could use sendSynchronousRequest on a background thread, but that is pointless when NSURLConnection and NSURLSession can be used asynchronously)